# function template for default values

Tags: c++

I've got some code here which uses special values to check if a variable is initialized.

```
#define NULLVALUE_FLOAT         -9999
#define NULLVALUE_INT           -9999
#define NULLVALUE_UINT          0
#define NULLVALUE_DOUBLE        -9999
#define NULLVALUE_LONG          -9999
#define NULLVALUE_LONGLONG      -9999
#define NULLVALUE_CSTRING       ""

bool isNull(float value) { return NULLVALUE_FLOAT == value; }
bool isNull(double value); ...
bool isNull(long value);...
bool isNull(int value);...
bool isNull(UINT value);...
bool isNull(CString value);...
```

So unsigned's special value is zero, signed ints and floating point is -9999 and string is the empty string.

Now I would like to rewrite this into one template function, but having problems with it because of the CString version. The best I can do is two functions, one for fundamental types and one for CString.

```
template<typename T,
    bool E = std::is_fundamental<T>::value && !std::is_unsigned<T>::value && (std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value),
    bool E2 = std::is_fundamental<T>::value && std::is_unsigned<T>::value>
bool isNull(const T &t) 
{ 
    if (E)
        return t == -9999;
    else if (E2)
        return t == 0;
    else
        return false;
}

bool isNull(const CString &  s)
{
    return s == "";
}
```

Is it possible to get this working with only one function, even when adding other classes with default values?

Comment: What you have is pretty minimal already. You could, if you tried, fold it into one with `constexpr if` in C++17.

Comment: Also, why bother with ugly macros if you are just going to write the literal in the function explicitly?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - What about the question you linked makes it a dupe? Template function specialization is hardly ever the answer to anything.

Comment: @StoryTeller I guess, but the question asks for a way to evaluate a different expression based on a template type, so I would say it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I read the question as asking how to make this only a single function, without overloading or specializing the function.

Comment: the macros are from the old code, wanted to remove them too

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't count specializations as different functions..

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen Do you think that the dupe is appropriate? If not, please say.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - You should. The standard does. Every instantiation is a separate function.

Comment: How about using `is_base_of`? Wouldn't that do the job?

Comment: Side note: for floating point types, you might prefer calculating `abs(value - null) < epsilon` to reduce rounding problems...

Comment: [OT]: `optional` seems more appropriate to handle "not initialized variable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution presents itself rather easily if you shift your focus away from defining the function, and onto defining the way to name Null values.

Add a traits class that exposes a `value` member. Specialize *that* however you find convenient.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct NullValueHolder{};

template<typename T>
constexpr decltype(NullValueHolder<T>::value) NullValue = NullValueHolder<T>::value;  
// Utility for easy referral 

template<typename T>
struct NullValueHolder<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && std::is_signed<T>::value>> {
  static constexpr T value = -9999;
};

template<typename T>
struct NullValueHolder<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>> {
  static constexpr T value = 0;
};

template<>
struct NullValueHolder<CString, void> {
  static constexpr const char * value = "";
};
```

The above makes heavy use of SFINAE. The `void` in the primary template must be matched by a specialization in order for that specialization to be picked. Each `enable_if_t` provides that `void` if the conditions are met.

Now the function writes itself:

```
template<typename T>
bool isNull(T const& t) { return t == NullValue<T>; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that C++17 is out for visual studio this can be solved rather easy with its "if constexpr" feature. Let the compiler generate the functions as needed.

```
template<typename T>
bool isDefault(const T &t)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_unsigned<T>::value)
    {
        return t == 0;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value)
    {
        return t == -9999;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, CString>::value)
    {
        return t == "";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, COleDateTime>::value)
    {
        return t.GetStatus() == COleDateTime::null;
    }
}
```